# Error: width suffixes are invalid in ARM mode

Tags: arm, clang, inline-assembly

I'm trying to manually issue ARMv7 `movt` and `movw` instructions for a cpu feature test. I'm catching a compile error with Clang.

The test program is below. According to the ARM folks, `.inst.w` is the way to do this. It handles big-endian and little-endian properly, and places the code in the `.text` section instead of a `data` section.

```
$ cat test.cxx
int test()
{
  int a;
  asm volatile (
        ".inst.w 0xf2412334  \n\t"   // movw r3, 0x1234
        ".inst.w 0xf2c12334  \n\t"   // movt r3, 0x1234
        "mov %0, r3          \n\t"   // mov [a], r3
        : "=r" (a) : : "r3");
  return a;
}
```

GCC is fine:

```
$ g++ -O1 -march=armv7-a test.cxx -c
$ objdump --disassemble test.o
...
00000000 <_Z4testv>:
   0:   f241 2334       movw    r3, #4660       ; 0x1234
   4:   f2c1 2334       movt    r3, #4660       ; 0x1234
   8:   4618            mov     r0, r3
   a:   4770            bx      lr
```

However, Clang:

```
$ clang++ -O1 -march=armv7-a test.cxx -c
test.cxx:5:2: error: width suffixes are invalid in ARM mode
        ".inst.w 0xf2412334  \n\t"   // movw r3, 0x1234
        ^
<inline asm>:1:2: note: instantiated into assembly here
        .inst.w 0xf2412334
        ^
test.cxx:5:25: error: width suffixes are invalid in ARM mode
        ".inst.w 0xf2412334  \n\t"   // movw r3, 0x1234
                               ^
<inline asm>:2:2: note: instantiated into assembly here
        .inst.w 0xf2c12334
        ^
2 errors generated.
```

If I change `.inst.w` to `.inst`, then Clang produces garbage:

```
$ clang++ -O1 -march=armv7-a test.cxx -c
$ objdump --disassemble test.o
...
00000000 <_Z4testv>:
   0:   f2412334        vcge.s8 d18, d1, d20
   4:   f2c12334        vbic.i32        d18, #5120      ; 0x00001400
   8:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
   c:   e12fff1e        bx      lr
```

I verified Clang is defining `__GNUC__`, so it should be able to consume this code.

How do I get Clang to assemble the `movt` and `movw` instructions?

Comment: Seems gcc compiles as thumb, clang doesn't. Does `-mthumb` do anything?

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that your GCC is configured to default to thumb mode, while clang isn't.

ARM has got two different 32 bit instruction sets, ARM and Thumb, and even if the instruction names are similar, the encodings are different. The ARM instruction set encodes all instructions as fixed length 32 bit instructions, while Thumb originally was a much smaller instruction set with all instructions being 16 bit. Since Thumb2 (which is the case for ARMv7), the instructions can either be a single 16 bit instruction or a pair of two 16 bit instructions.

The disassembly you showed indicates this:

```
   0:   f241 2334       movw    r3, #4660       ; 0x1234
   4:   f2c1 2334       movt    r3, #4660       ; 0x1234
   8:   4618            mov     r0, r3
   a:   4770            bx      lr
```

The latter two instructions are plain 16 bit opcodes (`4618` and `4770`), while the former two are two pairs of 16 bits (`f241 2334` and `f2c1 2334`) separated with whitespace.

The clang disassembly however doesn't split the opcodes in half, and have full 32 bit opcodes for all instructions:

```
   0:   f2412334        vcge.s8 d18, d1, d20
   4:   f2c12334        vbic.i32        d18, #5120      ; 0x00001400
   8:   e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
   c:   e12fff1e        bx      lr
```

In this case, passing `-mthumb` to Clang should get the same behaviour as GCC, and vice versa, passing `-marm` to GCC should reproduce the same failure there.

The `.w` suffix to `.inst` is to indicate that the value should be handled as a wide 32 bit instruction (as opposed to a narrow 16 bit one), which only makes sense in Thumb mode. IIRC, both GCC (since some time) and Clang (since release 8) should be able to deduce the kind of Thumb instruction without the `.w` suffix as well.

Instead of forcing the compiler to one mode or another, you probably want something like this instead though:

```
  asm volatile (
#ifdef __thumb__
        ".inst.w 0xf2412334  \n\t"   // movw r3, 0x1234
        ".inst.w 0xf2c12334  \n\t"   // movt r3, 0x1234
#else
        ".inst   0xe3013234  \n\t"   // movw r3, 0x1234
        ".inst   0xe3413234  \n\t"   // movt r3, 0x1234
#endif
        "mov %0, r3          \n\t"   // mov [a], r3
        : "=r" (a) : : "r3");
```